# How to write highlighted data into excel file using python?

Tags: python, excel

[image]I have written python program for highlighting some of keywords.please view screenshot.help me out how to write this line in excel using python same as

```
from termcolor import colored
text=[!['Hi How are you.fine by the grace of god?'][1]][1]
l1=['grace','god']
formattedText = []
for t in text.lower().split():
if t in l1:
    formattedText.append(colored(t,'white','on_red'))
else: 
    formattedText.append(t)

print(" ".join(formattedText))
```

Comment: so u want to highlight some cells in excel.like highlight cell A1 something like that?

Comment: yes,please how to do

Comment: The above screenshot is printed.how to write as it is in excel using python

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i have used openpyxl in this code as its more convenient and I will give you full guide on how to highlight cells with it.

first you import should be :

```
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
import openpyxl
```

then you might know this but still, I am telling you need to give path and select the active sheet out of that excel file:

```
path = r"THENAMEOFYOURFILE.xlsx"
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path, data_only=True)
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active
```

when you have the sheet active you need to bring colors I have two sample colors you can try search online for more colors.

```
ligth_red_color = PatternFill(start_color="FFC7CE", fill_type="solid")
green_color = PatternFill(start_color='8BB048', fill_type="solid")
```

now you can specify the cell you want to highlight by giving its row and column like for C3 its 3rd row and 3rd column.

```
cellC3 = sheet_obj.cell(row=3, column=3)
```

then you can take the fill component of the cellc3 and give it the value of any of the 2 sample color I gave before.

```
cellC3.fill = ligth_red_color   #change the color of cell C3 to red
cellC3.fill = green_color   #change the color of cell C3 to green
```

now don't forget to save the file otherwise the changes won't be saved

```
sheet_obj.save(r"FINALFILENAME.xlsx")
```

Hope you find these codes and explanation helpful

Comment: how can we specify specific column instead of one cell ?